# Matplotlib hist2d() and numpy masked_where()?

Tags: matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

I may be misunderstanding how `numpy.ma.masked_where()` works, but it doesn't seem to work properly with `matplotlib hist2d()`.

In the code below, I create an `ndarray`, mask it, then plot the original and masked `ndarrays` with `matplotlib.pyplot.plot()`.  This works.

However, when I try to plot both with `matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d()`, the mask doesn't seem to be taken into account.  I have tested this with matplot lib 1.3.1 and 3.2.1, and with numpy 1.18.5.

Any suggestions?

```
import math
import numpy as np
import time
import sys

import numpy.ma as ma

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import expon, poisson, uniform, norm

print(matplotlib.__version__, np.__version__)
nSiz=10000
maxx, maxy = 1.0, 10.0
x, y, z = uniform.rvs(scale=maxx, size=nSiz), uniform.rvs(scale=maxy, size=nSiz), norm.rvs(scale=1.0, size=nSiz)
binx, biny = np.linspace(0, maxx, 20), np.linspace(0, maxy, 20) 

d = np.array([(xx, yy, zz) for xx, yy, zz in zip(x, y, z)], dtype=[('X', 'f4'), ('Y', 'f4'), ('Z', 'f4')])

print("Col titles: " + str(d.dtype.names))

dc = ma.masked_where(d['X'] < 0.5, d)   # Mask data

fig, axx = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10, 10), dpi=300)
ax = axx.ravel()

ax[0].plot(d['X'], d['Y'], 'bv', ms=3)
ax[1].plot(dc['X'], dc['Y'], 'ro', ms=6, alpha=0.1) ### Mask seems to work

ax[2].hist2d(d['X'], d['Y'], bins=[binx, biny], cmap='Blues')
ax[3].hist2d(dc['X'], dc['Y'], bins=[binx, biny], cmap='Blues') ### Mask doesn't seem to work

for axx in ax:
    axx.set_xlabel(d.dtype.names[0], fontsize = 15)
    axx.set_ylabel(d.dtype.names[1], fontsize = 15)
    axx.set_xlim(0.0, maxx)
    axx.set_ylim(0.0, maxy)
    
ax[0].set_title('No cut')
ax[1].set_title('Cut')
plt.show()
```

The last plot is incorrect:

[image: Last plot is incorrect]

Comment: [plot hist2d with normalised masked numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253049/python-matplotlib-plot-hist2d-with-normalised-masked-numpy-array) suggests calculating with `np.histogram` and applying a mask to the result. As the histogram result is of another type than the input, the mask needs to be adapted. It is unclear whether that is possible in your desired use case.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out a simple solution in my case is not to use:

`dc = ma.masked_where(d['X'] < 0.5, d)`

but instead to simply replace that command with:

`dc = d[d['X'] < 0.5]`

That does the job for me (though I still don't know the purpose of `numpy.ma.masked_where()`).